# Codeigniter SET variable on query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I need to execute this query with Codeigniter query builder:

```
SET @row_number:=0;

SELECT Id, @row_number:=@row_number+1 as Position
FROM my_table
WHERE date='2015-12-26'
```

I can do it by using "$this-> db-> query" function like this:

```
    $query = 'SET @row_number:=0;';
    $this-> db-> query ($query);

    $query = 'SELECT Id, @row_number:=@row_number+1 as Position';
    $query = $query . ' FROM my_table';
    $query = $query . ' WHERE date=\'' . $data . '\''
```

But, my question is: Is there a way to do it without hard write the query, so writing something like this:

```
        $query = 'SET @row_number:=0;';
        $this-> db-> query ($query);
        #*****It's wrong!!!!*****

        $this -> db -> select(array('Id', '@row_number:=@row_number+1 as Position'));
        $this -> db -> from('my_table');
        $this -> db -> where('date', $data);
        $query = $this -> db -> get();
```

Answer (score 2):

No need to `pass array in select` you just write your query as

```
 $this -> db -> select('Id, @row_number:=@row_number+1 as Position');
```

Comment: It doesn't work because generated query is like this: *SELECT 'Id', '@row_number:=@row_number+1' as `Position` 
FROM 'my_table'*. I think there are two problems: 1-It doesn't consider the first part of query (SET @row_number:=0). 2-Using your solution it attaches quotes like *'@row_number:=@row_number+1'*

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would prefer to order the results by some column and add the desired position in a foreach loop, cause it's more efficient and it keeps the code cleaner imo, nevertheless it is possible.

The key to the solution is the second, optional parameter of the CI db select function, as it is pointed out in the [user guide](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html):

> $this->db->select() accepts an optional second parameter. If you set it to FALSE, CodeIgniter will not try to protect your field or table names. This is useful if you need a compound select statement where automatic escaping of fields may break them.

Like so:

```
$query = 'SET @row_number := 0';
$this->db->query($query);

$this->db->select(array('Id', '@row_number:=@row_number+1 as Position'), false);
$this->db->from('my_table');
$this->db->where('date', $data);
$query = $this->db->get();
```